# How to track Kubernetes OOMKilled termination messages?

Tags: kubernetes

When a Pod is evicted I'm supposed to find messages about the eviction at `/dev/termination-log` (or other path defined in `terminationMessagePath` property) inside the container filesystem.

I'm trying to track OOMKilled events, but after OOMKilled occured and the Pod was restarted, the `/dev/termination-log` is empty.
I tried to set `terminationMessagePolicy` property to `FallbackToLogsOnError` hoping to find out messages in container log and I did not find anything about the OOMKilled there.

By executing `kubectl describe pod podname` I can find out that the termination reason was OOMKilled, but I would like to be able to follow this events in order to integrate it with fluentd and logstash.

Our Kubernetes cluster version is v1.9.0 and it's running on-premise. The installation was done using kubeadm on top of CentOS 7.

Answer (score 5):

You can ssh to the machine the pod was running and exec `journalctl -u kubelet`

Comment: Thanks for answer. By reading logs for kubelet unit I can see that the container was restart, I can't determine the reason:
`Feb 23 11:10:00 kbnhml01 kubelet[1728]: I0223 11:10:00.973333    1728 kuberuntime_manager.go:514] Container {APP DETAILS IN JSON} is dead, but RestartPolicy says that we should restart it.`

Comment: Since it's OOMKilled, you can either run your docker container locally and monitor the heap and memory usage to make sure there's no memory leak or you can increase the memory limit specified in kube spec and see whether it will resolve the problem.

Comment: Pods that are OOMKilled are sent a SIGKILL by the kernel itself.  SIGKILL is untrappable, and the pod cannot have a dying message sent before it is killed.  Only the node itself will have any leftover messages about how Linux killed it, and only from its POV.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm using - is looking to dmesg on nodes and track events from there

Answer (score 1):

It might not return the error code, but it certainly shows more details.

> You can use `kubectl logs --previous` to retrieve logs from a previous
> instantiation of a container. If your pod has multiple containers,
> specify which container's logs you want to access by appending a
> container name to the command.

from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/